# Automatically start stracing process upon invocation

Tags: linux, system-calls, systemtap

The intention of below SystemTap script is to start `strace`ing whenever a process with a given filename is started.

It is called with the following command:

```
stap  -g -v './sstrace.stp' "$PATTERN"
```

Where PATTERN can for example be `mount`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stap

# Assign command line parameter to the variable.
@define target_filename %( @1 %)        # The regex the script will trigger on given as CLI parameter

probe begin {
  printf( "Probe starting ...\n" )
  printf( "Try to attach strace upon executing binary (regex) /%s/\n\n" , @target_filename )
}

probe end {
  printf( "Wrapping up ...\n" )
}

probe syscall.execve {
  if ( filename =~ @target_filename ) {
    start_trace( pid() )
  }
}

###
### FUNCTIONS
###

function start_trace( pid ) {
  raise( 19 )
  # Sleeping is bad practice in SystemTap probe, but don't know how to otherwise
  # wait for strace to initialize in time. This will not work as expected when
  # workting interactively. Compare these two results while increasing below sleep
  # to 1 second.
  # $ sudo ./go date
  # $ date; echo hi
  # $ bash -c 'date; echo hi'
  system( sprintf( "strace -f -p %i & sleep 0.01; kill -CONT %i" , pid , pid ) )
}
```

The idea is that I stop execution (`raise( -19 )`) of the target process long enough for `strace` to attach to the process and, then restarting the target process (`kill -CONT $TARGET_PID`). This often works, but unfortunately intermittent.

When it works, `strace` kicks in right after `execve()`, similar to this:

```
$ strace date 2>&1 | head
execve("/bin/date", ["date"], 0x7ffeb7ce6430 /* 64 vars */) = 0 
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5578de8fa000   <== strace kicks in here.
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_O............
```

Now the problem I really at least want to understand and hopefully solve, is the fact that on some systems I cannot `kill -STOP` the target process, it simply throws an error along the lines of: `kill: process xyz does not. exist`.

I know by the time the `execve` syscall is called, the PID already exists. What I don't understand is why it doesn't seem to obey the `SIGSTOP`.

Does anyone know why this happens, how to fix the SystemTap script or have an even smarter way to accomplish the goal starting to trace a process on the fly?

Comment: `on some systems I cannot kill -STOP the target process` - do you mean that the issue is absent on some systems while is reproducible in stable manner on other ones? If yes - can you provide more details about system where you face the issue? Linux distribution, kernel version, stap version, etc.

Comment: Just for info: `CentOS 7.6.1810`, kernel `3.10.0`, stap `3.3/0.172` - everything seems to work as expected.

Comment: To help debug this, can you add a call to `cat /proc/%i/status` after the `kill` command?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Currently it works (of course) ant it shows `state: T (stopped)`. Are you interested in specific fields? I cannot copy/paste from the VM at the moment. Let me give it a few shots try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Trying to reproduce with the `cat /proc/%i/status` in a while loop ... I'll update when I hit. Usually when it hits once, it stops working for a long time.

Comment: I'd like to see the state field of the status file, or an error message from cat, in cases where the kill command gets the does-no-exist error.

Comment: Have 2 VM's running non stop for about a week trying to reproduce, but it is apparently an intermittent thing :-(